# What combinations of "swaps" of elements in a list are equivalent?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, permutations, matlab

Define a swap-operation $s_{ij}=s_{ji}$ on an $n$-tuple $a_n=(1,2,\dots,n)$ as interchanging the elements in the $i$th and $j$th positions of the tuple.

I would like to find an efficient way to generate all *distinct* permutations resulting from applying $k<n$ such swaps, i.e., all distinct $S=s_1s_2\cdots s_k$, where the subscripts refers only to the order in which the swaps are applied; any of the swaps $1,\dots,k$ could be any of the possible $s_{ij}$ (but it is perhaps appropriate to exclude the possibility of having two adjacent and identical swaps, since they would just cancel).

---

**Example:**
For $n=3$, represent the tuple as a column vector and the swaps by the three $\left(\binom{n}{2}=3\right)$ possible $3\times 3$ matrices:

\begin{align}
s_{12}&=\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}\\
s_{13}&=\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0} \\
s_{23}&=\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0}
\end{align}

Then we can identify the results of applying $k=2$ such swaps:

\begin{align}
s_{12}s_{13}a_3^T&=\pmatrix{3 & 1 & 2}^T \\
s_{12}s_{23}a_3^T&=\color{red}{\pmatrix{2 & 3 & 1}^T} \\
s_{13}s_{12}a_3^T&=\color{red}{\pmatrix{2 & 3 & 1}^T} \\
s_{13}s_{23}a_3^T&=\color{blue}{\pmatrix{3 & 1 & 2}^T} \\
s_{23}s_{12}a_3^T&=\color{blue}{\pmatrix{3 & 1 & 2}^T} \\
s_{23}s_{13}a_3^T&=\color{blue}{\pmatrix{3 & 1 & 2}^T} \\
\end{align}

Note the duplicates. I would like to avoid calculating these. Could I have known from the start that $\color{red}{s_{12}s_{23}=s_{13}s_{12}}$ and $\color{blue}{s_{13}s_{23}=s_{23}s_{12}=s_{23}s_{13}}$, without actually calculating these?

---

So far, I've checked the result of all permutations of operations (giving the six scenarios in the example above), and then thrown out the duplicates, but my computer quickly chokes.
**Is there a way to go directly to the unique results for a given $n$ and $k$?** In my present problem, $n=9,$ but a generalization would be nice.

I'm using Matlab, but pseudo-code or strictly mathematical considerations are both very welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Lots of stuff is in principle known about this sort of thing, one natural setting being combinatorics of Coxeter groups. You can look up books on that subject for various results about reduced words and exchange relations and so on.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. I'm afraid I know nothing about Coxeter groups. Any introductory resources you'd recommend I look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common way to describe a permutation is via its cycle decomposition. A permutation $\sigma$ specified by $\sigma(1)=4$, $\sigma(2)=5$, $\sigma(3)=2$, $\sigma(4)=1$, $\sigma(5)=3)$, $\sigma(6)=6$, $\sigma(7)=7$ can be described by writing down its cycles $$\begin{cases} 1 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 4 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 1\\ 2 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 5 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 3 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 2 \\ 6 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 6 \\ 7 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 7\end{cases}$$ which we usually shorten to $(1\;4)\;(2\;5\;3)\;(6)\;(7)$ or sometimes just $(1\;4)\;(2\;5\;3)$. (But for the purposes of this answer, we'll want to keep track of the length $1$ cycles as well.)

Each permutation has a cycle decomposition that's unique up to rotating a cycle (we can write $(2\;5\;3)$ as $(5\;3\;2)$ and that's still the same) and up to writing the cycles in a different order.

Moreover, knowing the cycle decomposition tells us how many swaps we need to get a given permutation. For example, we get the cycle $(2\;5\;3)$ by applying the swap $(5\;3)$ and then applying the swap $(2\;5)$; in general, we can get $(a_1\;a_2\;\cdots\;a_k)$ by applying $(a_1\;a_2)$ after $(a_2\;a_3)$ after ... after $(a_{k-1}\;a_k)$, which takes $k-1$ swaps.

Counting the $1$-cycles or fixed points, this tells us that we can obtain a permutation with $t$ cycles by doing $n-t$ swaps: If the cycles have length $\ell_1, \ell_2, \dots, \ell_t$, then $$(\ell_1-1) + (\ell_2-1) + \dots + (\ell_t-1) = n-t.$$ We also can't do any better: each swap can reduce the number of cycles by at most $1$, since at best it can combine two cycles into one cycle.

With $k$ swaps, we can get all permutations with $n-k$ cycles; also, all permutations with $n-k+2, n-k+4, \dots$ cycles, since we can insert as many pairs of redundant swaps as we like. Each swap reverses the sign of a permutation, so we can't get permutations with $n-k+1, n-k+3, \dots$ cycles in any way.

So if you want to find all the permutations that can be obtained with $k$ swaps, find all the cycle decompositions that have $t$ cycles, where $t \ge n-k$ and $t \equiv n-k \pmod 2$.

---

Here's an example. Suppose we have $n=5$ and we allow ourselves $k=2$ swaps. Then we can get permutations with $n-k=3$ cycles, or $5$ cycles. (The $5$ cycle case is when we do the same swap twice, and get back to the identity permutation, which you might not want to count.)

The $3$ cycles have total length $5$, which could be $3+1+1$ or $2+2+1$. We'll handle these cases separately:

- If the cycles have lengths $3$, $1$, and $1$, we'll want to choose the $3$ elements of the $3$-cycle (in $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways) and then choose the ordering on the $3$-cycle (in $(3-1)!$ ways). These are: 
  $$(1\;2\;3)\;(4)\;(5) \qquad (1\;3\;2)\;(4)\;(5) \\
  (1\;2\;4)\;(3)\;(5) \qquad (1\;4\;2)\;(3)\;(5) \\
  (1\;2\;5)\;(3)\;(4) \qquad (1\;5\;2)\;(3)\;(4) \\
  (1\;3\;4)\;(2)\;(5) \qquad (1\;4\;3)\;(2)\;(5) \\
  (1\;3\;5)\;(2)\;(4) \qquad (1\;5\;3)\;(2)\;(4) \\
  (1\;4\;5)\;(2)\;(3) \qquad (1\;5\;4)\;(2)\;(3) \\
  (2\;3\;4)\;(1)\;(5) \qquad (2\;4\;3)\;(1)\;(5) \\
  (2\;3\;5)\;(1)\;(4) \qquad (2\;5\;3)\;(1)\;(4) \\
  (2\;4\;5)\;(1)\;(3) \qquad (2\;5\;4)\;(1)\;(3) \\
  (3\;4\;5)\;(1)\;(2) \qquad (3\;5\;4)\;(1)\;(2)$$ For each of these, we can represent it as a product of the $s_{ij}$'s by factoring $(i\;j\;k)$ as $s_{ij}s_{jk}$: e.g., $(1\;3\;5)\;(2)\;(4)$ is the product $s_{13} s_{35}$. (That's $s_{13}$ done after $s_{35}$.)
- If the cycles have length $2$, $2$, and $1$, we have $5$ cases on what the odd element out is, and then $3$ ways to pair up the remaining $4$ elements into two cycles:
  $$(1\;2)\;(3\;4)\;(5) \qquad (1\;3)\;(2\;4)\;(5) \qquad (1\;4)\;(2\;3)\;(5) \\
  (1\;2)\;(3\;5)\;(4) \qquad (1\;3)\;(2\;5)\;(4) \qquad (1\;5)\;(2\;3)\;(4) \\
  (1\;2)\;(4\;5)\;(3) \qquad (1\;4)\;(2\;5)\;(3) \qquad (1\;5)\;(2\;4)\;(3) \\
  (1\;3)\;(4\;5)\;(2) \qquad (1\;4)\;(3\;5)\;(2) \qquad (1\;5)\;(3\;4)\;(2) \\
  (2\;3)\;(4\;5)\;(1) \qquad (2\;4)\;(3\;5)\;(1) \qquad (2\;5)\;(3\;4)\;(1)$$ These are particularly easy to write in terms of $s_{ij}$'s: for example, $(1\;3)\;(4\;5)\;(2)$ is $s_{13} s_{45}$ in any order. (In general, each cycle in the cycle decomposition gives us some swaps, and swaps from different cycles can be interleaved however we like without changing the permutation.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still a bit in the dark as to how I can implement this. Could you perhaps apply it to the example in my question? How can all the cycle decompositions with the properties specified in your last paragraph be found without actually looking at all the combinations of the operations $s_{ij}$?

Comment: Okay, I'll edit in an example.

Comment: I did $n=5$ instead of $n=3$ because if we do $n=3$ with $k=2$ swaps, we get $n-k=1$ cycle, and there's only two such permutations: $(1\;2\;3)$ and $(1\;3\;2)$. You have three permutations in your example, but I think you computed $s_{23} s_{13} a_3^T$ incorrectly: $s_{13} a_3^T$ is $(3,2,1)^T$, so $s_{23} s_{13} a_3^T$ is $(3,1,2)^T$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: **Q1)** For some cycle of length $l$, say $(2\;4 \;5\;1)$ for $l=4$, is it always true that it can be represented by $l-1$ swapping-matrices, in this case $A:=s_{51}s_{45}s_{24}$? If yes, can the total permutation, say $(2\;4 \;5\;1)(1\;6)(7)$ then be represented $ABI$, where $B:=s_{16}$ and $I$ is the identity and where $AB=BA$ (they commute because they represent distinct cycles, right)?

Comment: **Q2)** If I want to implement this, I'd first need to find the number of partitions of $n$ into $n-k$ cycles (two ways in your example and, for instance, four for the case of $n=9$ and $k=5$, correct?), and then find all permutations of these disregarding the permutations that are cyclically identical (e.g. $(1\; 2\;3)=(2\;3\;1)$ and so on). Finally I would have to represent these permutations as matrices, and then I have my permutations (in a form that I can work with). Is this a viable strategy? Do you see any shortcuts? Thanks again.

Comment: Q1) Yes, but it should be $s_{24} s_{45} s_{51}$ instead.  Q2) Yes, that's the idea; it'll take a while, but that's because there's a lot of permutation matrices to find. I see six ways to break $n=9$ up into $n-k=4$ cycles: $6+1+1+1$, $5+2+1+1$, $4+3+1+1$, $4+2+2+1$, $3+3+2+1$, $3+2+2+2$

Comment: Of course, left multiplication.. Haha, I somehow got $9-5=5$.. :S. I tried searching for an expression that would tell me how many such ways there should be (so I can check if if I forgot any), but I came up empty-handed. This expression would be the [composition number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Composition.html) $C_k(n)$, but where order didn't matter. Is there any easy way of correcting for this that you can see? Perhaps one can give such an expression in terms of a [partition function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html)?

Comment: Btw, do only answer this if it interests you, you have done more than enough!

Comment: Yep, "partition" is the keyword you're looking for. Wikipedia calls this an "integer partition" and uses the notation $p_k(n)$. OEIS has a page on these: http://oeis.org/A008284